# Where is the BitmapEncoder in a Windows Phone 8.0 project?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

This might be a really silly question, but I'm on my first Windows Phone application. I'm unable to reference (or find) the Windows.Graphics.Imaging namespace that contains the BitmapEncoder class.

I'm in a Windows Phone 8.0 project and if I try to add references it tells me I have them all. I'm seeing sample after code sample of people using the BitmapEncoder but I can't seem to find it.

I'm almost at a point to use the Browse in add references and add it that way, I just want to make sure I'm not going to mess something up down the road.

Edit: I'm starting to believe that it could be because the project is 8.0 instead of 8.1. I'm going to backup and convert and see if that resolves it.

Comment: After converting up to 8.1, I do see the Windows.Graphics.Imaging namespace. But I have a host of errors with a non-existant Version.txt file and of course NuGet versioning issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BitmapEncoder only for universal app and Windows Phone 8.1

See [BitmapEncoder class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder)

Comment: I mean Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder class. And Aloisdg write about System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapEncoder. They are not equivalent and you have to understand that you require in your task.

Answer (score 0):

BitmapEncoder exist in both WindowsPhone 8.0 & WindowsPhone 8.1.

> Plateformes
>
> Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 7, Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)